# Set Google map marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hi i have a Google Map that automatically check for user location and put the location to center. I am having problem with putting the marker at the center. I am currently adding marker when you click somewhere.

I also want to clear existing markers when another position is clicked.

```js
var markers = [];
window.onload = function() {

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
      map.setCenter(pos);

    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  }

  var mapOptions = {

    center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.3891, 39.8579),

    zoom: 15,

    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

    disableDefaultUI: true,

  };

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);


  // This event listener calls addMarker() when the map is
  // clicked.

  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);

  });

  function placeMarker(position, map) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map
    });
    map.panTo(position);
  }


  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {

    document.getElementById("lat").value = (e.latLng.lat());

    document.getElementById("lng").value = (e.latLng.lng());

    div = document.getElementById('name');
    div.style.display = "block";

    div = document.getElementById('submit');
    div.style.display = "block";

    var element = document.getElementById('spacing');

    element.style.margin = null;

  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA-2vW1cIR0t0ZVfVdCmcxx0QEV4C3l6hk&callback=myMap"></script>

<div id="map" style="width:100%; height:505px ; z-index: 1;">


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi added this code to the existing code to add marker to center:

```
infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
map.setCenter(pos);
```

> var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  position: pos,  animation:
>   google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,  icon: 'img/mapicon.png' });
>
> marker.setMap(map);

```
},
function() {
handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the secoind solution, i added this :

```
                              function placeMarker(position, map) {

                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                              position: position,
                              icon: 'img/mapicon.png',
                              map: map
                            });
                            map.panTo(position);
                            markers.push(marker);

                          }

                          function setMapOnAll(map) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                              markers[i].setMap(map);
                            }
                          }


                          function clearMarker(position, map) {

                            setMapOnAll(null);
                          }
```